# how to fix mining software make error? bfgminer bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory, mining-software, bfgminer

so i have bfgminer up on a linux machine running fine purring away at 67Mh/s solo mining (geforce gtx460)

im attempting to build on a windows 10 machine

i have tried msys2 mgwin32 and 64 bit

nothing seems to work i get errors in all stages: autogen, configure and make

im using mgwin64bit now and got to the make stage succesfully...

i am able to autogen, configure but when it comes to make i get an error:

```
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/virtu/bfgminer/libblkmaker'
  CCLD     bfgminer.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: bfgminer-miner.o:miner.c:(.rdata$.refptr.cpus[.refptr.cpus]+0x0): undefined reference to `cpus'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1340: bfgminer.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/virtu/bfgminer'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2844: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/virtu/bfgminer'
make: *** [Makefile:1209: all] Error 2
```

Could someone help me come up with a solution?

in the meantime i will return to mingw32 and attempt to fix the no gcc or c compatible compiler issue on autogen/configure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error in miner file, something to do with cpus

`./configure with enable cpu mining` fixed this

now able to make bfgminer

note similar issue from other users:

https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/issues/787

Comment: ./configure --enable-cpumining && make

Answer (score 0):

./configure --enable-cpumining && make